# How do I change the time zone in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working on a time app for JS and I was wondering, how could I change the time zone. See, I live in the eastern time zone of North America, and i don't like converting it to the International Timezone. So here is my Code.

```
<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = Date()">
 Click me to display Date and Time.</button> 

<p id="time"></p>
```

When I click the button, I get,

```
Wed Dec 30 2015 13:40:25 GMT+0000 (UTC)
```

But I want it to be:

```
Wed Dec 30 2015 8:40:25 (EST)
```

Comment: What timezone is your client configured as?

Comment: The library moment.js can be useful for you.

Comment: Eastern Standard Time

Comment: If it is then when [Date.prototyope.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) is called then it should give you a value in that timezone. What browser are you using, perhaps it's a bug within the browser?

Comment: @Xotic750 it says    "Invalid Date"

Comment: Huh??? What are you saying? `toString` is implicitly called when you do `innerHTML = Date()`

Comment: Input: Date.prototype.toString()
Output: "Invalid Date"

Comment: @caballerog I don't want to use an external JS

Comment: I'm using Chromium 22 for Debian 7.8

Comment: @PattonPierce It can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070604/how-to-convert-datetime-from-the-users-timezone-to-est-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date.prototype.toString` is supposed to give you a string in your local time (as configured on your client).

When you click `Run code snippet` this should show an alert dialog with your local time string (`toString` is implicitly called, like in your example);

```js
alert(new Date());
```

If it does give you the expected result then either you client timezone is not configured correctly or the browser you are using is bugged.