# How to set date always to eastern time regardless of user's time zone

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

I have a date given to me by a server in unix time: 1458619200000

**NOTE: the other questions you have marked as "duplicate" don't show how to get there from UNIX TIME. I am looking for a specific example in javascript.**

However, I find that depending on my timezone I'll have two different results:

```
d = new Date(1458619200000)
Mon Mar 21 2016 21:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

// Now I set my computer to Eastern Time and I get a different result.

```
d = new Date(1458619200000)
Tue Mar 22 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

So how can I show the date: 1458619200000 ... to always be in eastern time (Mar 22) regardless of my computer's time zone?

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439630/how-do-you-create-a-javascript-date-object-with-a-set-timezone-without-using-a-s

Comment: i think this is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834411/specify-timezone-in-javascript

Comment: I looked through all those but didn't understand it to well. I'd like a code example for what I'm trying to do specifically... they don't answer that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert datetime from the users timezone to EST in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070604/how-to-convert-datetime-from-the-users-timezone-to-est-in-javascript)

Comment: This one is right http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834411/specify-timezone-in-javascript/

Comment: Seems like you are looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString .

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can easily take care of the timezone offset by using the [getTimezoneOffset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) function in Javascript. For example,

```
var dt = new Date(1458619200000);
console.log(dt); // Gives Tue Mar 22 2016 09:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

dt.setTime(dt.getTime()+dt.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000);
console.log(dt); // Gives Tue Mar 22 2016 04:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

var offset = -300; //Timezone offset for EST in minutes.
var estDate = new Date(dt.getTime() + offset*60*1000);
console.log(estDate); //Gives Mon Mar 21 2016 23:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

Though, the locale string represented at the back will not change. The source of this answer is in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16048201/1455421). Hope this helps!

Comment: is your unix time always in EST timezone? If so then you need to add the correct GMT offset for your input (-4 hours), then translate THAT to the local time zone by adding the local timezoneoffset() back into the unix time before creating a new date object.

Comment: what are you setting the time to, utc? how do I set it to a specific timezone

Comment: @foreyez From the UTC time, its easy to convert to any fixed timezone. You can simply add or subtract the timezone offset in the date object by using `setTime()`. For example, if your fixed timezone is UTC+10 (Australian Eastern Standard Time), `+600*60*1000` will be the offset you can add to your time.

Comment: although it's easier to just d.setHours(d.getHours() - 5); to convert it to eastern

Comment: This does not take into account daylight savings.  For instance EST is -5 hrs in the winter and -4 hrs in the summer

Answer (score 13):

Moment.js (http://momentjs.com/timezone) is your friend.

You want to do something like this:

```
var d = new Date(1458619200000);
var myTimezone = "America/Toronto";
var myDatetimeFormat= "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss a z";
var myDatetimeString = moment(d).tz(myTimezone).format(myDatetimeFormat);

console.log(myDatetimeString); // gives me "2016-03-22 12:00:00 am EDT"
```

Comment: I don't want to use moment

Comment: yes but it adds a problem for me to download library, add it to my source code, change all my existing code to fit with it, etc etc as opposed to what I'm looking for: which is two lines of javascript that I can't figure out.

Comment: however +1 your answer bc I'll use this if I don't get any other answers :P

Comment: Thank you. You can write your own function that does this, but it would involve reinventing the wheel, somewhat. 

See http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/6016329/

Comment: note: this didn't work. even if I use the example above, the time changes based on my local timezone. I think it's a problem with "new Date"

Comment: For my codebase, moment + moment-timezone has added 500kb to the size of the application since it's not tree shakable. If you want smaller bundle sizes, moment may not be the best solution to use.

Comment: For this to work, you have to know your timezone and hard code it?

Answer (score 3):

For daylight saving, Eastern time become 4 hours behind UTC. That's why its offset is -4x60 = -240 minutes. So when daylight is not active the offset will be -300. The `offset` variable's value is the key point to be noted here. Kindly see this code in action in attached image.

```js
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();// getting offset to make time in gmt+0 zone (UTC) (for gmt+5 offset comes as -300 minutes)
var date = new Date();
date.setMinutes ( date.getMinutes() + offset);// date now in UTC time
            
var easternTimeOffset = -240; //for dayLight saving, Eastern time become 4 hours behind UTC thats why its offset is -4x60 = -240 minutes. So when Day light is not active the offset will be -300
date.setMinutes ( date.getMinutes() + easternTimeOffset);
```

[image: You can see this code in action here in this image]

Comment: do we still have daylight saving in Florida?

Comment: This is cleaner to change the minutes rather than the time.