# Javascript Timezone change for the given specified timezones

Tags: javascript, html

[How to set date always to eastern time regardless of user's time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36206260/how-to-set-date-always-to-eastern-time-regardless-of-users-time-zone/36206597)

I referred the above link for apply timezones.

THe below code is working fine for EST

```
 var dt = new Date();
console.log(dt);
alert(dt.getTimezoneOffset());

dt.setTime(dt.getTime()+dt.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000);
console.log(dt); 

var offset = -300; //Timezone offset for EST in minutes.
var estDate = new Date(dt.getTime() + offset*60*1000);
console.log(estDate);
```

Here the offset is  var offset = -300; for EST. Similarly I have the list of timezones like

```
CST, MST, PST, AKST, HST
```

Here how to calculate the offset for each .  Or any other better way to calculate date time `new date()` with this timezones.

Comment: Whats you question ?

Answer (score -1):

The offset may be different in summer/winter depending if there is a daylight saving time for the timezone. It could be cumbersome implementing it yourself and prone to bugs. I would use a library for that, for example momentjs with moment-timezone plugin https://momentjs.com/timezone/